# Not able to register compute node(liberty) on cotroller (kilo) -

Tags: virtualization, openstack

I am unable to get my compute node server registered on controller getting below error:

```
2016-10-23 14:11:08.486 6305 WARNING nova.virt.libvirt.driver [req-f8748c61-09f8-425c-82c0-2ceff4865d9e - - - - -] Cannot update service status on host "open2" since it is not registered.
```

please help